# How to use the created objects from get_or_create method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Here if the object created I want to use this object in another model. How can I do it ?
I suppose `created` returns the Boolean value so How can I get the created object ?

```
value, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(field1=field1, field2=field2)
if created:
     another_model_obj.manytomanyfield.add(created)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the `value`, this is the object that is created:

```
value, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(field1=field1, field2=field2)
if created:
     another_model_obj.manytomanyfield.add(value)  # ← use value
```

The [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method returns a 2-tuple:

> Returns a tuple of `(object, created)`, where **`object` is the retrieved or created object** and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

So the first line "*unpacks*" the 2-tuple into two variables `value` and `created` where `value` is the object that is either obtained (if it already exists), or created (if it did not yet exists).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Initially I thought `value` returns only if objects already exists.